# Что такое dim?

Tags: vba

Допустим, есть строка Dim Цена As Long
или Dim Срочность As Single
что обозначается эти словоформы?

Answer (score 3):

Объявляет и размещает в памяти одну или несколько переменных.
[Смотреть подобнее тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Насколько помню по школе VB Dim это объявление переменной то есть Объявляется переменная Цена тип Целое число и тп